# Problema en relacion de seguridad symfony

Tags: seguridad, symfony3

Hola tengo que un usuario puede tener uno o varios certificados y un certificado solo pertenece a un usuario

esta es la entidad usuarios

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{

     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $idcertificado;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Certificado", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idcertificado", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $certificado;
```

....

Y la entidad certificado

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * certificado
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="certificado")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CertificadoRepository")
 */
class certificado
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="certificado")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

....

El Controlador para crear un nuevo usuario es

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
        $user->setPassword($encoded);
        $user->setUsername($user->getEmail());
        $user->setRol('admin'');//Este solo es el rol de usuario
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush($user);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

El formulario es

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username')
        ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
        ->add('email',EmailType::class)
        ->add('isActive')
        ->add('idcertificado',ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Seleccione el rol' => null,
        'Basico' => 1,
        'Avanzado' => 2,
                       )));
    }
```

Al momento de guardar el idcertificado viene nulo. No entiendo porque. Esto solo me pasa con esto. Con la relacion de una entidad normal no me pasa esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vayamos por partes hay varias cosas:

- En la entidad usuario no debes guardar el *idcertificado* como tal, al guardar el objeto *Certificado* ya podrás obtenerlo instanciando el usuario y con algo similar a *$user->getCertificado()->getId()*. Es mas, en la tabla de la base de datos se guardará el id del certificado en ambos campos si lo haces como tienes escrito, es redundante.
- No sé si afectará pero llama a la clase certificado -> Certificado.
- Lo último y lo más importante, es que el formulario de User no está bien construido. Fuera de saber si tienes implementada la función *setIdcertificado* (que sería como ya te he dicho una muy mala práctica) deberías utilizar EntityClass del siguiente modo:

`->add('certificado', EntityType::class, array(
   'class' => 'AppBundle:Certificado',
   'choice_label' => 'nombre_o_el_campo_que_quieras',
));`

Deberías exponernos pese a todo algo más como están construidas tus clases para poder ayudarte. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Perfecto elimine eso como dijiste y use entityType class

Comment: Muchas gracias. Resolviste mi duda

Comment: De nada, marca pues mi respuesta como correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo hice me estaba dando problemas marcando la pregunta correcta. Mira si ya te quedo porque creia que ya lo habia hecho